# How to get a row object from a function that return a table object in plsql?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

i'm trying to get a single row and save it into a variable in PLSQL.

I'm using APEX and all is around the APEX_DATA_PARSE.PARSE() function.
As the docs said, .PARSE() should return WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW for every row of results.

What i'm trying to do is to get only one row to be saved into a variable.
This is My code:
`

```
DECLARE
    r_columns_headers  WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW; --object
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
    BEGIN
        <<populate_headers>>
            select * into r_columns_headers
            from apex_application_temp_files f,
            table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                      p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                      p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
                      P_SKIP_ROWS                   => 1,
                      p_max_rows                    => 500,
                      p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                      p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p
            where f.name = '43300947378776117/DATALOAD_Test_data_main_v032.xlsx' and p.line_number = 2;
        end populate_headers;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_columns_headers.id);
    end;
```

`

is just for test outside the main package that i'm writing.
The error i get is PL/SQL: ORA-00947 on row 8, on the select * into r_columns_headers section.
I don't know why i get not enough values, the fields are the same as they are the same type of object. The select return exactly one row, of a WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_TABLE object. Not all columns are with data, someones are null, is this the problem?
I'm just at the beginning of learning plsql.
Thanks a lot

```
wwv_flow_t_parser_row
```

I'm trying to get a row into the r_columns_headers variable to access it in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ORA-00947: not enough values" error is sometimes a bit confusing; in a PL/SQL context it can be backwards.

The problem is that you actually have too *many* values in your select list. You are doing:

```
select * into r_columns_headers
```

but you're joining two table expression, `apex_application_temp_files` as `f` and the unnested table as `p`. So the `*` is effectively doing:

```
select f.*, p.* into r_columns_headers
```

... and that object doesn't have fields for all the columns coming from `f`.

So you need to restrict it to the relevant data:

```
select p.* into r_columns_headers
```

... but that returns all of the object attributes as individual columns, not as a single object; but you can get the actual object with [the `value()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/functions-and-operators-useful-with-objects.html#GUID-6BA5D983-5B94-49C2-BDD7-7B2B7E15B117):

```
select value(p) into r_columns_headers
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XTpVndoY) with a dummy object type and data as the real APEX types aren't available there.

Comment: Hi thank you for your kind respond. I've thinked the same (i'm still trying to get it work) but even limiting the select to p.* return the same error. I've managed to change the NLS LANGUAGE setting to english to post here the complete error. (the change in the code is only the p.* )

Comment: [2022-12-22 19:22:36] [65000][6550]
[2022-12-22 19:22:36]  ORA-06550: line 8, column 13:
[2022-12-22 19:22:36]  PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
[2022-12-22 19:22:36]  ORA-06550: line 7, column 13:
[2022-12-22 19:22:36]  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @execcr - right... `p.*` gives you the scalar field values as columns, not a single object, which is kind of the point of it... I've updated to use `value(p)` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot i didn't know the VALUE function. I've tested and i can save correctly the result into my object alias and get the columns i need! :)